# Showing minimum between x and y is a primitive recursive function with initial functions

Tags: logic, computability

for $f(x)=min(x,y)$ with this formula:
\begin{equation}
min(x,y) =
\begin{cases}
x & \text{  x<y} \\
 y & \text{ y<x} \
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
how we can show it's primitive recursive with initial functions?

Answer (score 1):

For showing $f(x)$ function is primitive recursive with any formula we must generate $f(x)$ function with initial functions or functions that can built with initial functions. in this problem, we can do it by the following steps.

- Extended subtraction is primitive recursive

  $
  x ∸  y =
  \begin{cases}
  x-y & \text{  x ≥ y} \\
   0 & \text{ x < y} \
  \end{cases}
  $
- Negation function is primitive recursive

  $
  \alpha(x) =
  \begin{cases}
  0 & \text{  x = y} \\
   1 & \text{ x ≠ y} \
  \end{cases}
  $
- So by combining these two we can have

  $
  \alpha(x ∸  y) =
  \begin{cases}
  1 & \text{  x ≥ y} \\
   0 & \text{ x < y} \
  \end{cases}
  $
- And multiplication is primitive recursive and we can generate this

  $y.\alpha(x ∸ y) =
  \begin{cases}
  y & \text{  x ≥ y} \\
   0 & \text{ x < y} \
  \end{cases}$
- And the final step is this

  $min(x,y) = y.\alpha(x ∸ y) + x.\alpha(y ∸ x)$

So min(x,y) is premitive recursive.